# Remove consecutive duplicate rows on the basis of a column

Tags: python

I am struggling with a problem which is explained below. I am sharing incomplete python script also which does not work for this problem. I would be grateful if get support or instruction for my script.

my tab delimited file look like this:

```
+   5     1364182    TTGC
-   5     1364204    GATG
+   1     9372980    TTCA
-   1     9373028    GGAA
+   2     14029383   ACCA
-   2     14029437   ACCA
-   1     19815169   AGTT
-   1     19815254   CCGT
+   4     13475195   AGCA
-   4     13475251   TCTC
-   5     64182      TTGC
-   5     64204      GATG
+   1     9372980    TTCA
-   1     9373028    GGAA
+   2     14029383   ACCA
-   2     14029586   ACCT
```

I my trying to remove the whole rows on the basis of first column (which is + and -) if it duplicates consecutively except the first match. The output should look like:

```
+   5     1364182    TTGC
-   5     1364204    GATG
+   1     9372980    TTCA
-   1     9373028    GGAA
+   2     14029383   ACCA
-   2     14029437   ACCA
+   4     13475195   AGCA
-   4     13475251   TCTC
+   1     9372980    TTCA
-   1     9373028    GGAA
+   2     14029383   ACCA
-   2     14029586   ACCT
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

gff = raw_input("Enter the gff file: ")
gff_file = open(gff, "r")
f1 = open("f1", "w")

for line in gff_file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.split("\t")
        x = line[0]
        for line1 in gff_file:
                line1 = line1.rstrip()
                line1 = line1.split("\t")
                y = next(line1[0])
                if x != y:
                        f1.write(x + line1[0]+"\n")
```

I am unable to compare first column entry with consecutive same column entry.
The file is very large so one liner is not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate more! Your example is not readily understandable!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `y = next(line1[0])`?

Comment: Why would you remove `-   1     19815169   AGTT`?

Comment: Actually he is removing `-   1     19815169   AGTT` and `-   1     19815254   CCGT`!

Comment: @Dataman I have edited the example please have a look

Comment: This `-   2     14029586   ACCT` is extra in your example!

Comment: Would you delete an instance like this as well? `+   1     19815169   AGTT` and `+   1     19815254   CCGT`? If yes you should update your question again! I mean if two + comes after each other with the same chromosome number? ;)

Comment: I have reedited sorry for this

Comment: @Coder256 I am trying to remove the consecutive duplicate rows on the basis of first column entries. In this case the - sign is same as just above so the row is removed. The very next line is also remove for same reason. I have updated my example for better understanding please have a look.

Comment: Is the second column `chromosome number`? If yes, I guess you should not delete lines 7 and 11 since the `minus strand` you see in the previous lines (lines 6 and 10) are coming from another chromosome. So, I guess you should do the cleaning based on both first and second column! Is that true?

Comment: @Dataman Yes you are right. The second column is chromosome and the first col is orientation mapped reads. Because its paired end data i want to rid out from the pair which are mapping with same orientation and and more or less at same position of the chromosomes. I already removed the pairs of which both reads are mapping to different chr or same chr but really far apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is not a programming exercise and you just want to clean the data, switch to `awk`.  It's not even a one-liner.

```
$ awk 'p!=$1{p=$1; print}' file

+   5     1364182    TTGC
-   5     1364204    GATG
+   1     9372980    TTCA
-   1     9373028    GGAA
+   2     14029383   ACCA
-   2     14029437   ACCA
+   4     13475195   AGCA
-   4     13475251   TCTC
+   1     9372980    TTCA
-   1     9373028    GGAA
+   2     14029383   ACCA
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're basically grouping by clusters of the first symbol (`+` or `-`), and you want to keep only the first.  This is a good use case for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("data.gff") as fp_in, open("data_reduced.gff","w") as fp_out:
    grouped = groupby(fp_in, key=lambda x: x.split("\t")[0])
    for key, group in grouped:
        fp_out.write(next(group))
```

`groupby` accepts an iterable (here the input file `fp_in`) and a key function, which I'm passing as `lambda x: x.split("\t")[0]`, meaning "take the line, split it by tabs, and give me the first element".

It yields pairs containing a key (which here will be `+` or `-`) and an iterator over all the elements of the group -- in this case, the contiguous groups of lines starting with the same sign.  We select the first with `next(group)` and write it out.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
consec_lines = False
x = None
for line in gff_file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split("\t")
    if line[0] == x:
        consec_lines = True
        continue
    x = line[0]
    consec_lines = False
    for i in line+"\n":
        f1.write(i)
```